# Tag synonyms: [insects] -> [bugs]

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms

These two tags seem to have an awful lot of overlap. The [bugs](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bugs) tag description basically says it's a superset of [insects](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/insects). I think we should make [insects](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/insects) a synonym of [bugs](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bugs), as I don't think there will be many questions here that require the distinction (insects have 6 legs, bugs can have any number).

Answer (score 8):

I agree, I think that [insects](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/insects) should be made a synonym of [bugs](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bugs).  Like you said, they overlap and nearly 100% of questions don't require a distinction between bugs and insects, especially in the tagging.